# What is a good way to test Struts 1.3 actions when they have collaborators fetched from a JNDI resource?

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee

I am working on a web application involving Struts 1.3, some session beans and some EJB's.

The Struts action classes do a JNDI lookup to fetch a stateless session bean which implements the service layer of the application. This session bean in turn talks to DAO objects which are also stateless session beans, which talk to the entities.

Struts Action -> Service (stateless session bean) -> DAO (stateless session bean) -> Entity

I am contemplating a few approaches, and need help in understanding their pros and cons.

1. I am thinking of creating a ServiceFactory and a ServiceFactoryProvider. The test cases will re-configure the ServiceFactoryProvider to return a TestServiceFactory which will yield mocks of the stateless session bean that implements the service layer.
2. Yet another approach would be to override the JNDI directory in the test cases so that the normal JNDI lookup fetches mock objects.
3. A third approach is to use a property file which specifies the fully qualified name of the ServiceFactory. For production code this file will contain the name of the production factory, and for test code, we will have another file in the test classpath which will contain the name of the test factory.